# ElasticSearch : TypeError: expected string or buffer?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, elasticsearch, kibana

I wrote a simple python script to put the JSON file to Elasticsearch.I want to store it based on the id field I am extracting from the JSON file.
But when I try to insert into elastic search.It raises an error `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Here is the code I am working on...

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import requests
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import json
es = Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost','port':9200}])
r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:9200')
i = 1
if r.status_code == 200:

        with open('d1.json') as json_data:
                d = json.load(json_data)

                for i in d['tc'][0]['i]['f']['h']:
                        if i['name'] == 'm':
                                m = i['value']
                                dope=str(m)
                                print dope
                                print type(dope)
                                #print type(md5)
                                es.index(index='lab', doc_type='report',id=dope,body=json.loads(json_data))
```

Error Log:

```
44d88612fea8a8f36de82e1278abb02f
<type 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "elastic_insert.py", line 22, in <module>
    es.index(index='labs', doc_type='report',id=dope,body=json.loads(json_data))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this error.I even tried to convert the m to `int` but it gave another error.

```
int(m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '44d88612fea8a8f36de82e1278abb02f'
```

P.S: ElasticSearch service is up and running.

Comment: Not being a python expert, the problem comes obviously from the json.loads method. Care to share the json file you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not related to the id. the problem is with
"json_data". it is a file stream so you need json.load and not json.loads in your es.index